# Python: updating priorities in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, priority-queue

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
tasks = [{'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 15},
{'priority': 10, 'task': 'french', 'complete_time': 90},
{'priority': 5, 'task': 'geography', 'complete_time': 45},
{'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 100}]
```

I would like to update this list by changing the priorities from zero ongoing so that I get:

```
[
{'priority':0, 'task':'math', 'complete_time': 15},
{'priority':0, 'task':'math', 'complete_time': 100},
{'priority':1, 'task':'geography', 'complete_time': 45},
{'priority':2, 'task':'french', 'complete_time': 90},
]
```

I have started by listing the set of all possible priority values:

```
tasks_set = list({x['priority']:x for x in tasks}.values())
```

which gives:

```
 [{'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 100},
 {'priority': 10, 'task': 'french', 'complete_time': 90},
 {'priority': 5, 'task': 'geography', 'complete_time': 45}]
```

but am stuck after this!

Comment: Would you describe your problem? I couldn't understand what do you need?

Comment: I would like to automatically 'compact' the priority numbers from the first list to the second: 'priority = 2' becomes 0, 'priority'=5 becomes 1, 'priority'=10 becomes 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple solution:

```py
from pprint import pprint

tasks = [
    {'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 15},
    {'priority': 10, 'task': 'french', 'complete_time': 90},
    {'priority': 5, 'task': 'geography', 'complete_time': 45},
    {'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 100}
]

priority_set = list(sorted({task["priority"] for task in tasks}))
priorities_updater = {}
for i in range(len(priority_set)):
    priorities_updater[priority_set[i]] = i

for i in range(len(tasks)):
    tasks[i]["priority"] = priorities_updater[tasks[i]["priority"]]

pprint(tasks)

# output
# [{'complete_time': 15, 'priority': 0, 'task': 'math'},
# {'complete_time': 90, 'priority': 2, 'task': 'french'},
# {'complete_time': 45, 'priority': 1, 'task': 'geography'},
# {'complete_time': 100, 'priority': 0, 'task': 'math'}]
```

You may observe that the `priority` attribute in the tasks is no longer the first one in the set, this is normal for Python `set`s, which are un-ordered (contrary to the `list`s), and for which the default behavior is then to sort the keys by alphabetical order.
Here we first build a set with all the priorities using [set comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) (`{task["priority"] for task in tasks}`). Then we sort the values for them to be in ascending order. Finally, we convert the set to a list (not really necessary here, but a habit I've taken if the indices of the elements are significant).
When this is done, we build a dictionary in which the keys are the old priorities, while the values are the new ones.
Finally, we go through the `tasks` dictionary and update the priorities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it "sorted" function, you don't need to casting for set type;

```
from pprint import pp

tasks = [{'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 15},
         {'priority': 10, 'task': 'french', 'complete_time': 90},
         {'priority': 5, 'task': 'geography', 'complete_time': 45},
         {'priority': 2, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 100}]

sorted_task = sorted(tasks, key=lambda val: val['priority'])

for order, task in enumerate(sorted_task):
    task['priority'] = order

pp(sorted_task)

# output: 
# [{'priority': 0, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 15},
#  {'priority': 1, 'task': 'math', 'complete_time': 100},
#  {'priority': 2, 'task': 'geography', 'complete_time': 45},
#  {'priority': 3, 'task': 'french', 'complete_time': 90}]
```

If you want to sort by reverse, just add "reverse=True" parameter.

Comment: I think what the original post is about is to change the priorities for them to still be in the same order, but scaled back to having the first priority equal to 0 and a step of 1 between each of them

Comment: From what I have gathered, similarly prioritized tasks should still get the same priority after the update.